# Too many redirects - access from LAN

Tags: php, redirect

I need to redirect index.php to login.php. I use following code

```
<?php header("Location: localhost/project/login.php"); ?>
```

"project" is the directory where I stored files. This works fine on my localhost. But I need to access this from another machine on my LAN

I modified above code to reflect my IP

```
<?php header("Location: 192.168.1.2/ajith/login.php"); ?>
```

Then I get an error "you have too many redirects" and seems "192.168.1.2/ajith/login.php" has repeated in the address bar.

any advice is highly appreciate.

Comment: If index.php and login.php are in the same folder you can just do: Location: login.php

Comment: ohh yes, it gives me the correct result. So, using relative path is work. Thanks a lot